# How to get a vertical scrollbar in HTML output from Jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When running the following code in Jupyter Notebooks using an excel with 500 rows:

```py
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.min_rows', 50)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50)
df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
display(df)
```

I can click on the left side of the output to get a vertical scrollbar on the output window. When I export this notebook either via nbconvert or the build in "download as; HTML" I just get the 50 rows of data and no vertical scrollbar. Is there any way to keep the dataframe small (In the end I would like to show all 500 rows in an output window with a scrollbar)

[HTML table in Jupyter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/khWc1.png)
[HTML table in export](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm0w4.png)

Comment: So you get some HTML? Did you check if your missing rows are actually in there?

Comment: I might not have explained it correctly, I've added pictures of what it looks like in the notebook and the export.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to insert CSS with help from this blog post: 
http://damianavila.github.io/blog/posts/mimic-the-ipython-notebook-cell-execution.html

in this way I could insert:

```css
overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 500px;
```

in all the output cells

Comment: where did you add the CSS?