# How to add a vertical scrollbar in html output from jupyter notebook with nbconvert?

Tags: pandas, jupyter, scrollbar, nbconvert, longtable

I am automatizing some reports with jupyter and exporting it to html. I have some large tables, and I want to add a scrollbar to rigthside of table. A similar question is here: [How to get a vertical scrollbar in HTML output from Jupyter notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975567/how-to-get-a-vertical-scrollbar-in-html-output-from-jupyter-notebooks). Here are a reproducible example:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

    np.random.seed(2021)

    df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['a'] * 50 + ['b'] * 50,
              'var_1': np.random.normal(size=100),
              'var_2': np.random.normal(size=100)})
```

I think it could be done using .css styling, but I'm having dificulties to apply it. Pandas have some useful methods for styling tables (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). Then, I tryed the following:

```py
   vscrollbar = {
     'selector': 'div.output_html',
     'props': ' height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;'
   }

   df.style.set_table_styles([vscrollbar])
```

After that, I compile the notebook from CLI with

```sh
   jupyter-nbconvert example.ipybn --to-html
```

The output don't show the right scrollbar. But if I inspect the html code, the style that I passed throw Pandas is there

```html
...
<style type="text/css">
#T_e24f1_ table {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
</style>
<table id="T_e24f1_">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="blank level0">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col0">type</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col1">var_1</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col2">var_2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
...
```

I don't know if I'm passing the right selector, or if jupyter is overwriting this style.

How can I get a right scrollbar for long tables in html output from jupyter nbconvert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list of things you should know.

1. `selector` is a method that could help you to select one or several elements in html. So, maybe, you need to learn about how to use it. For your example. It should be `''`, cause, if you ever checked what the code output in `ipynb`, you will see like this below.

```css
#T_f2ffe_  div.output_html{
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

The first part `#T_f2ffe_` is generated randomly by `pandas` and the second part `div.output_html` is what you write. And these `selectors` will work **`together`**, and that will cause you to not specify any elements

2. A `table` in html, its height is calculated in two aspects, the `td` height and the number of `td`. If you want the `css height` to work, you'd better add `display:inline-block` first.

---

So here is the final answer that will work by little change.

```py
vscrollbar = {
 'selector': '',
 'props': ' height: 500px; overflow-y: scroll;display: inline-block;'
}

df.style.set_table_styles([vscrollbar])
```

And the html looks like.

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your explanation, this works fine. Is there a way to fix the header in scrolling?

Comment: @Mentoldo does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47923622/5587080

Answer (score 2):

An option to implement a vertical scrollbar is using the following code:

```
display(HTML("<div style='height: 200px'>" + df.style.render() + "</div>"))
```

You can change the layout and position of the scrollbar to whatever you want. The output looks like this:

[image]