# Display cell scrollbar in Jupyter Notebook on GitHub

Tags: github, jupyter-notebook, scrollbar

A cell output in one of my Jupyter notebooks has a vertical scrollable side bar. When I added this notebook to my GitHub repository, the full output (which takes up a lot of space) was displayed. Is it possible for GitHub to display the cell output with a sidebar?

Below is a minimal working example illustrating the problem. Here is a screenshot of a cell in a Jupyter Notebook that has a scrollbar:

[image]

If this notebook is converted to HTML via `jupyter nbconvert --to html name.ipynb` and viewed in a browser (to replicate publishing and viewing the notebook on GitHub), then the output looks like this (there is no scrollbar):

[image]

I found the following related links, but no one has posted a solution yet:

- [How to get a vertical scrollbar in HTML output from Jupyter notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59975567/how-to-get-a-vertical-scrollbar-in-html-output-from-jupyter-notebooks)
- [How to add a vertical scrollbar in html output from jupyter notebook with nbconvert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68628383/how-to-add-a-vertical-scrollbar-in-html-output-from-jupyter-notebook-with-nbconv)

Any help would be appreciated!